# Is there a way to subscript a Perl function which returns an array without using an intermediate variable

Tags: perl

When a Perl function returns an array is it possible to subscript the returned array?

```
my @tkeys = keys(%$someHashRef);
my $a0 = $tkeys[0];
# following not allowed by Perl
my $b0 = keys(%$someHashRef)[0];
```

Is there any way to extract an array element as a scalar from a function returning an array without using an intermediate array variable?

Comment: Btw, in Perl scalars are returned, so it'd be a "list" (collection of scalars), not an "array" (a multi-valued _variable_).  "Just" terminology this particular distinction matters a bit

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subscript the subroutine/function call, but you can add parens and subscript those:

```
my ($value) = ( function() )[0];
```

Or using your example:

```
my $b0 = ( keys(%$someHashRef) )[0];
```

Comment: I think uses references makes the intention clearer.   `$result = [function()]->[0]`

Comment: @mob, Pretty sure that anyone that can figure out `[...]->[0]` can figure out `(...)[0]`, and it only creates N-1 needless scalars instead of the 2N of your approach

Comment: In this case the ()[] approach will work well because in this specific case the hashRef is guaranteed to have a single key.  But the general case appears to be something that SQL optimizes for (a SELECT ... LIMIT without an ORDER BY clause) while in Perl, Lisp, and many languages there is no equivalent optimized or lazy evaluation of the array.  In clojure which I use often lazy evaluation is part of the core.  I wonder if Perl 6 supports generators and lazy sequences.

Comment: @JohnDaschbach And for a question about how to subscript a function in those languages, another answer would be correct. For Perl however, this is the way to subscript a function, which is what you asked for. Was there some other answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list slice (`( LIST )[ INDEXES ]`).

```perl
my $b0 = ( keys( %$someHashRef ) )[ 0 ];
```

Better yet, a list assignment would do the trick.

```perl
my ( $b0 ) = keys( %$someHashRef );
```

In this particular case, you can also use

```perl
my $b0 = each( %$someHashRef );
keys( %$someHashRef );   # Reset iterator.
```

This latter approach avoids creating a scalar for each key of the stash.